# Is there a built-in text-to-graphic utility for OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, graphics

I believe I've seen one or more utilities, possibly command-line or Applescript, which will take a string and create, for example, an image containing that text with the specified font size, etc.

I can't find it again. Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) doesn't come with OS X, but it should though.

`convert -background skyblue -border 10 -bordercolor skyblue -fill 'hsb(10%,50%,50%)' -font /Library/Fonts/Arial\ Narrow.ttf -pointsize 24 label:"some text" output.png`

If you have to specify some more complex styles, using [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) might be easier.

```
echo "<style>em {padding:5px}</style><em>Test</em>" > test.html
webkit2png test.html --clipwidth=55 --clipheight=35 --scale 1 -C
```

Comment: You should save temporary files to `/tmp` rather than the desktop, just in case rm fails for some reason and the user sees a new file on their desktop.

Comment: Thanks.  This product seems to create a screen shot of a webpage, if I understand correctly, a bit of a long way around.  I really think there's a simple utility that does  text-to-jpg (say) directly.

Comment: Right, agreed, but in this case I'm looking for just the bare bones, being able to specify the font name and size, period.

Answer (score 0):

[Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) will do what you want, I believe. It's not built-in.